# GSON throwing “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY”

Tags: android, json, gson

My class:

```
public class MyClass { 

    public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, PointFMP[] >> matchingPages;

    public static class PointFMP{
        public float x;
        public float y;
    }
}
```

My Json:

```
{
    "matchingPages": {
        "1": {
            "Butter": [
                {
                    "x": 16.23,
                    "y": 21.11
                },
                {
                    "x": 18.18,
                    "y": 26.67
                }
            ],
            "Cake": [
                {
                    "x": 13.23,
                    "y": 21.11
                }
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            "Other value": [
                {
                    "x": 41.98,
                    "y": 47.62
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Parsing:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyClass response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

My error:

> 11-29 12:56:47.017: W/System.err(8169):
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 11-29
>   12:56:47.022: W/System.err(8169):     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)

Any idea how to properly parse it?

Comment: BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING means, when gson was de-serialiizing your json the matchingPages key "1" is string not an int/integer that why gson says its "1" , "2" keys are the string not the Integer objects.

Comment: I don't think it's that, because changing public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, PointFMP[] >> matchingPages; to public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, PointFMP[] >> matchingPages; doesn't help and I parse in other place with public Map<Integer, BrochureItem> items; following json "items": { "146226": {

Comment: see i have replied with PointFMP and Butter class, your json format is correct. oh i think you did not see that matchingPages in your json is string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Gson fromJson throw a JsonSyntaxException: Expected some type but was some other type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621808/why-does-gson-fromjson-throw-a-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-some-type-but-was-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not valid Json. It should look like this:

```
{
    "1": {
         "Butter": [
         {
            "x": 16.23,
            "y": 21.11
        },
        {
            "x": 18.18,
            "y": 26.67
        }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "Butter": [
        {
            "x": 41.98,
            "y": 47.62
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not it. I've just copied part of json. I've updated my question, so json could be validated.

Comment: I accept your answer, because it seems SOMETIMES input json was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is correct you can parse it as below

```
   public class PointFMP {

    @SerializedName(value="Butter")
    List<Butter> butter;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PointFMP [butter=" + butter + "]";
    }
}


public class Butter {

    public double x;
    public double y;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PointFMP [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, PointFMP> categoryMap  =
 gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, PointFMP >>>(){}.getType());
```

result will be as below

```
{1=PointFMP [butter=[PointFMP [x=16.23, y=21.11], PointFMP [x=18.18, y=26.67]]], 2=PointFMP [butter=[PointFMP [x=41.98, y=47.62]]]}
```

Comment: I cannot copy paste your code, because my Json is actually bigger than that (but error is in the fragment which I quoted here. when I comment out in MyClass field matchingPages then it parses). So I replaced my declaration of this variable with yours  public Map<String, Map<String, PointFMP >> matchingPages; and I get the same error. Why do you replaced PointFMP[] with PointFMP ? PointFMP is an array...

Comment: Also @SerializedName(value="Butter") is not allowed, because value Butter can be any other string - it's variable value will be different on other requests.

Comment: Actually in json matchingPages start from these braces {} means its an object not an array, thats why i replaced it. one thing  after this "1":{  // this is an object
         "Butter":[ // this is an array
            {
              inside Butter array you have an object.

Comment: I see your point. Do you think then that it's possible to parse it if value "Butter" can be any other string?

Comment: Yes you can do it more well , but you have to write custom class and your custom class implements JsonDeserializer

Comment: any tip how to do that? btw. take a look at updated Json in the question. Perhaps it was not obvious before that it's really Map<String, PointFMP[]>

Comment: Go here https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide            through custom deserialize , using reader and streaming api you can do

Comment: sure I know this page, but I have no Idea how could I use it. Anyway it seems that I was right. The error was somewhere else. I think somewhere returned json was incorrect, but for the case in my question my solution was good.